# Convert Gregorian to Chinese Lunar Calendar

Tags: php, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to understand how i can improvise this PHP script for Gregorian to Chinese Lunar calendar conversion.

The main downside of this php script is that the calendar conversion can only do up to year 2020. I need to extend the conversion years to as far as i can. Would appreciate for any help/guide.

Do i just add on in the "var $everyCMonth" array? It seems to me some number of days in a month but yet otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Chinese lunar calendar is one of many calendars described in *Calendrical Calculations* by Nachum Dershowitz and Edward M. Reingold (3rd ed., 2008, Cambridge U. Press). It is based on astronomical events; it is **not** an arithmetic calendar. In an arithmetic calendar like the Gregorian calendar, all the rules are self-contained within the calendar. In astronomical calendars like the Chinese lunar calendar, certain calendar dates are determined by the true time of astronomical events such as new moons. One can convert between two arithmetic calendars such as Julian and Gregorian by just examining the rules for the two calendars; conversion between an arithmetic and astronomical calendar requires going outside the rules of the calendars and performing astronomical calculations.

Dershowitz and Reingold provide simplified astronomical calculations that allow for conversions reasonably close to the present (you'll have to read the book to figure out how far in the future you can go before the calculations break down). For past dates, there were numerous reforms of the Chinese calendar which would have to be consulted in order to do conversions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I really need this book!